# Assigning classes to dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop

I have some code that creates a certain number of divs depending on how many elements are in the backend. I'm trying to dynamically create new classes for each of those divs.

For now I have:

```
<div class="cat-box">Title</div>
<div class="cat-box">Title</div>
// these divs are created with JavaScript
```

And I want them to become:

```
<div class="cat-box cat-num-0">Title</div>
<div class="cat-box cat-num-1">Title</div>
```

I found some code on SO that I implemented in, but I think there's a complication with having the original divs created dynamically and not hardcoded into my HTML.

Any thoughts on this?

#### JS snippet:

```
loadCategories(){
        let categs = _categories;

        let htmlElems = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
                htmlElems += "<div class='cat-box'>" + categs[0].Title + "</div>";
                $(".cat-box").each(function(i) {
                    $(this).addClass("cat-num-" + (i + 1));
                });
            }

        let container = document.querySelector("div.top-training");
        container.innerHTML = htmlElems;
        console.log(container);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch:

```
htmlElems += "<div class='cat-box'>" + categs[0].Title + "</div>";`
```

to:

```
// or: cat-num-" + (i + 1) + "
htmlElems += "<div class='cat-box cat-num-" + i + "'>" + categs[0].Title + "</div>";
```

Then remove the `$(".cat-box").each(...)` loop.

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thanks! It felt strange having the `.each` in there.

Answer (score 1):

On of the core features of the DOM is that you can programatically create nodes instead of concatenating HTML strings.

```js
let categories = [{title: 'Foo'}, {title: 'Bar'}, {title: 'Baz'}];
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

categories.forEach(function(cat, i){
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = cat['title'];
  div.className = "cat-box cat-num-" + (i + 1);
  frag.appendChild(div);
});

document.querySelector('div.top-training').appendChild(frag);
```

```html
<div class="top-training"></div>
```